# How to set a List of URIs for Images in a seperate XAML-File

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ControlElement` called `MultiImageDevice` which is an Element that should be initialised with a List/Array of URIs for images that I want to be able to switch through.

XAML-Code for the MultiImageDevice:

```
<component:AbstractDevice x:Class="View.MultiImageDevice"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:component="clr-namespace:View"
         x:Name="userControl"
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100">
    <Canvas Initialized="Level1Canvas_Initialized" Height="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=ActualWidth}">
        <Canvas Initialized="Level2FrameworkElement_Initialized">
            <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding Path=ImageSources[0], RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type component:MultiImageDevice}}}"  Height="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=ActualWidth}">
                <Image.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Opacity="0.5" ShadowDepth="3"/>
                </Image.Effect>
            </Image>
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</component:AbstractDevice>
```

and the C#-Code (without using directives):

```
namespace View
{
    public partial class MultiImageDevice : AbstractDevice
    {
        private double _currentImage = 1d;
        internal string[] ImageURIs { get; set; }

        public MultiImageDevice()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public override void PositionChangedSignal(ComponentIdentifier identifier, double position)
        {
            if (_currentImage != position)
            {
                _currentImage = position;
                //Switching shall occur here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And last but not least the call in the seperate XAML:

```
<component:MultiImageDevice Height="60" Canvas.Left="56.104" Canvas.Top="409.859" Width="60">
    <component:MultiImageDevice.ImageURIs>
        <x:Array Type="sys:String">                         
            <sys:String>
                pack://application:,,/img/AuxReleaseCancelButton_pushed.png
            </sys:String>
        </x:Array>
    </component:MultiImageDevice.ImageURIs>
</component:MultiImageDevice>
```

The problem with this approach is a compiler error stating that I can't add a `ArrayExtension-Type` to a `String[]-Type`. I also tried leaving the `<x:Array>-part` or declaring the Array as a `Resource` in the `MultiImageDevice`, which brought up new problems. So I'm at a loss now. I would be grateful for any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: This is MSDN page describing an string array in XAML http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752340.aspx. Maybe you're missing namespace specification.

Comment: I read that and I have the namespace specification :)

Comment: Do you really get a compiler error, or is it only a warning in XAML editor? When i try something like this, it warns me in XAML, but nevertheless it runs. To avoid the warning, you could put the array in the component's resource dictionary.

Comment: It shows a compiler error described at the end of my question. I could paste it here but it's in german. But interesting that it runs for you. Maybe it's some side effect I will look into that.

Comment: Ok I see it now. It runs but there is a problem with the build in **Designer**. It just won't load the XAML...

Answer (score 1):

I found this [page](http://soumya.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/wpf-simplified-part-11-xaml-tricks/) with this example

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemsSource>
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
      <sys:String>John</sys:String>
      <sys:String>Paul</sys:String>
      <sys:String>Andy</sys:String>
    </x:Array>
  </ListBox.ItemsSource>
</ListBox>
```

The `ItemSource` property is of `IEnumerable` type. So I changed `string[]` to `IEnumerable` (`IEnumerable<string>` is not working) in my dummy control and it works. The disadvantage is that you loose the type checking.

I also had problems with the plain property and I have to create an attached one for `Urls`.

Comment: Yes, seems like the array `Type` is not resolved at compile time. `object[]` would also work.